# match html tags that are not commented out

Tags: java, regex

I want to match script tags not commented out. To that end I was trying to use this regex:

```
(?is)((?<!<!--(?!-->))<script[^>]*>)
```

The logic was to ask it for `<script[^>]*>` not preceded by `<!--` which is, in turn, not followed by `-->`, but apparently `(?!-->)` does not stop at `<script[^>]*>` and goes all the way to `-->` after it. How do I tell it to stop at `<` in `<script...` ?

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1702990) link may be compulsory in this situation.

Comment: Darn it! I'll be the first one to chime in with that link someday...:)

Comment: Would it help if I ask for regex to capture all "a" that are not between "b" and "c" instead?

Comment: @Quirliom JSoup will be the option ?

Comment: @LittleChild Or any other decent HTML parser. Any one worth its salt should strip out any commented tags.

Comment: @Quirliom The answer you pointed to is a real gem. I swear it made my day !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it, you can search all commented content before, and after, as an alternation, search script tags and put this subpattern in a capture group:

```
<!--(?>[^-]+|-(?!->))*-->|(?i)(<script[^>]*>(?>[^<]+|<(?!/script>))*</script>)
```

Then the result is in the capture group.

If you want to use the `replaceFirst()` method, you can use:

**pattern**

```
(?i)((?><!--(?>[^-]+|-(?!->))*-->|[^<]+|<(?!script))*)(<script[^>]*>(?>[^<]+|<(?!/script>))*</script>)
```

**replacement**

```
$1 ### what you want ###
```

*(or use a capture group 2 in a callback function)*

Comment: I should have said I wanted it to work with .replaceFirst() :)